# Youtube v3 API Python Transition to live

Tags: python, youtube-livestreaming-api

I am trying to transition a broadcast event to testing and then to live using the youtube live API v3 with python 2.7.3. I used the example code in the youtube documentation web to create the broadcast, streaming and bind them but now I need to do the transition and there is no example of this in the documentation.
I am trying to do it using this code:

```
def bind_transition(youtube, broadcast_id):
        transition_state_response = youtube.liveBroadcasts().transition(
        part="status",
        id=broadcast_id,
        broadcastStatus="testing"
        ).execute()
```

Please someone can correct my code or give me an example for this.

Comment: What version of python are you using?

Comment: My Python version is: 2.7.3

Answer (score 0):

I had not written the main..., so I just defined the function but I was not actually using it, adding this code solved my problem:

```
        try:
          bind_transition(youtube, broadcast_id)
        except HttpError, e:
          print "An HTTP error %d occurred:\n%s" % (e.resp.status, e.content)
```